# How exactly was the Second Temple destroyed?

Tags: ancient-history, building, historical-techniques, jerusalem

What is known regarding the techniques used to destroy the Second Temple?

It was quite a large set of buildings made of stone blocks, and Romans didn't know (afaik) explosive techniques good for such destructive actions.

Was it used to build something else, or just turned into a pile of stone blocks?

Comment: Piles of stones would invariably be used to build other stuff.

Comment: Large stone buildings can be broken down with wooden wedges.

Comment: Destroying a building no matter how large, it a trivial matter, and very little "technique" is needed, if you have enough people. No comparison with building one.

Comment: Edit the question to make it more informative to viewers.
Please add context, as to what feature is the OP referring to

Comment: The Romans certainly had better cranes and techniques than the builders had, and gravity worked for them.

Comment: Start with Josephus' "The Jewish War". In it, he claims that the entire Temple Mount was consumed by a massive inferno. Hard to imagine that the 2nd Temple could be done in by fire alone, but there are plenty examples from history (and today) of large stone buildings being structurally-weakened by fire to the point of collapse.